# crontab does not really start schedule

Tags: laravel, cron, schedule

IN a laravel I have a SnapShot method to copy data to a statistics model.

When I run

```
/var/www/laravel/artisan  schedule:run
```

data are added to the Statistics-table.

Now I have added the following line to /etc/crontab

```
* * * * *  php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> dev/null 2>&1
```

In my /var/log/syslog I read:

```
 Jul 16 08:53:01 cluego CRON[24524]: (root) CMD (cd /usr/bin/php7.4  && php artisan schedule:run /dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 16 08:53:01 cluego CRON[24523]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jul 16 08:54:01 cluego CRON[24599]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run /dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 16 08:54:01 cluego CRON[24598]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

The laravel.log shows:

```
[2021-07-16 09:25:01] production.ERROR: No arguments expected for "schedule:run" command, got "/dev/null". {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Exception\\$
[stacktrace]
```

when I run manually I get the following result:

```
root@xxxx:/var/www/laravel# php artisan schedule:run
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.4' 'artisan' statistics:snap > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

and a data point is added to Statistics-table, just as it is supposed to.

Can anyone see why the cronjob is not running the statistics:snap command, just like the manual schedule:run does?

Comment: did you reload the cron & restart it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your coron job is wrongly formatted. From the documentation it should look like this:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

So in your case it should look like:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/laravel && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I guess you could also try running your version but with the full path to php instead of only `php` or using `/dev/null` instead of `dev/null`

```
* * * * *  php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

```
* * * * *  /path/to/php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thnak you. Apperently I used a wrong tutorial here. Your answer did it!!